# Upload fails for _some_ users

Tags: file-upload

When most people try to upload a (certain?) file that is big (60 megs) but not at our maximum allowed (90 megs), they receive:

Error Code 10054: Connection reset by server

after several minutes of trying. The network administrator set the connection timeout to 2000, but it makes no difference.

Of course, when the network folks attempt this same upload it works--like lightning.

Comment: Looks like differences in network speeds from some areas that make slow it down enough to make the difference.

Hard to tell from that error what exactly is timing out.

Answer (score 1):

check your ULS log and event log around the time of the incident. Should give you a good indication of whats going on. Agree with Nat that it could be a timeout due to slow connection